# Memory editing howto create more storage

Tags: string, unicode, arrays, memory-editing

I'm working on a problem using the Cheat Engine software. I have located an array of 12 bytes in memory that I would like to change. The problem is that the array holds 6 double byte unicode characters. I need to modify the string, witch I can do. I'm stuck at how I can give myself more storage for more characters. I can't simply write more characters to the address because I overrun and crash the application. Concept wise I'm wondering if its feesable to redirect the process reading the memory to somewhere where I can store more characters. But how do do something to that effect is beyond me at the moment.

D.

Comment: Is the string null-terminated or length-prefixed? If it's null-terminated *and* you can figure out who is referring to it, perhaps you could create new memory elsewhere and put your new string there and change all references to the address... but that's tedious and risky at best, and quite possibly it's worse than that...